# Google Map view shows only grey screen with zoom button

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Using android Google map API-2 for my application. When clicking map view it shows only a screen with zoom button.

my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.burusoth.advertise"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.View_Advertisements"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view__advertisements" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.Gadget_view"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gadget_view"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.Activity_post_advertisements"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_post_advertisements" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.Post_Advertisement"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_post__advertisement" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.Popup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_popup" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.burusoth.advertise.Google_Map"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google__map" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAKCvpyR3v4YStDJDoibNgoblkdch0F254" />


</application>
```

```
my activity xml file


 <RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Google_Map" >

   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my Activity .java Activity file for calling map
    public class Google_Map extends Activity {

```
private GoogleMap googleMap=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google__map);

     try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_google__map, menu);
    return true;
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap =((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

}

Comment: refer this one for Android Maps API v2 API Key Generate.. http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-maps-android-api-v2-tutorial.html

Comment: it is your api key generation problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here with I would like to share one example which run under Google Map API v2.
You can go through that steps or else you can download full example from below link.

This is working example. Please test this in real device.

[Google Maps API v2 using Android](http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/09/google-maps-android-api-v2-with-source.html)

Please provide your comment if you have any question.

Comment: i checked in real device by exporting apk file. still it shows grey screen with zoom button

Answer (score 0):

You need to put API_KEY in android manifest
Get from :
[Google Map API_KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Comment: Add a minimal explanation in the answer itself, as the link provided may happen to unavailable in the future.